# PHP - что значит <=

Tags: php

В коде наткнулся на такую строчку:

```php
$variable = function1() <= function2();
```

Вообщем вопрос, что делает `<=`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Логический оператор меньше или равно...результат true или false

Answer (score 0):

В данном конкретном случае проверяется, является ли значение, возвращаемое `function1()` меньше или равным значению, возвращаемому `function2()`.  Если данное условие выполняется - `$variable` будет присвоено булево `true`, иначе булево `false`.

Answer (score -1):

Значение function1() меньше или равно значения function2() соответственно переменная $variable получит true или false

function1() - обязана что-то возвращать
и
function2() - обязана что-то возвращать

Не знаю лично мне такой стиль не по душе))